# I can't find or use Pillow on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I need to use Pillow so I install it using this command

`python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow`

and now it does appear like this:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
Pillow     7.2.0
pip        20.2.3
setuptools 47.1.0
```

But I cannot use it on PyCharm and does not appears in my "site-packages" folder

I'm running

PyCharm 2020.2.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-202.6948.78, built on August 25, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.8+10-b944.31 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 982M
Cores: 4

On my win 10 student version x64

Comment: On PyCharm, go to Settings -> Project: ProjectName -> Project interpreter and check if the package appears there, if not, press the green plus (+) sign, search for it there and install the package. Sometimes (especially when you have multiple versions of python) the default python command doesn't use the same version as pycharm, that might be your case, but it's anyway simpler and easier to install packages via PyCharm

Comment: Thank you! .... You're right! :)